# How to ignore spell checking in Android lint using lint.xml or gradle script?

Tags: android, android-studio, lint, spelling

I tried using

```
<issue id="Typos" severity="ignore"/>
```

But it showing Spelling -> Typo error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It warning not by lint. It is an internal tool for Android Studio. If you want to disable typo warning, you need to do it Settings>Editor>Inspection>Spelling>Typo.[image]